# Error. An error occurred while processing your request. ASP.NET Core MVC 2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have trouble with working my site on IIS Server.
I read and tried the recommendations from Stack Overflow and other sites, but without success.
When installing the site on the IIS Server Version 10.0.17134.641 (on the my  local computer) the following error occurred:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3axd.png)

During development everything all worked fine. And when I try to post a site on local IIS Server, such an error occurred. Home page show normal. But when I try to register or log in have error above.

I'm confused because:
1) The publication took place in the "Folder", on the IIS pointed the way to it.
2) I'm install: Runtime & Hosting Bundle 2.2.3 for ASP.NET Core/.NET Core on Windows from this site: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/thank-you/dotnet-runtime-2.2.3-windows-hosting-bundle-installer
And in the module of my site are present: AspNetCoreModule, AspNetCoreModuleV2
3) I'm set "Application Pool" for this site in IIS Server next: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS5kM.png)
4) I'm "Edit Permissions..." for this site where I added and allow all permissions for next users: IUSR, IIS_IUSRS to "Security"
5) Also turn on next Windows features: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POD7h.png)

Site written on ASP.NET Core MVC 2.2 with Use Entity Framework Core also the same version

With what it can be connected?
With database connection?
Or with configure IIS Server?
Or configure Website?
Thanks:)

**SOLVED:**
1) I have to add: 'app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();' in Configure method Startup.cs file my project - It's help to show more details for errors.
2) In Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio need create a new user in `Security` -> `Logins` (in the same nesting level as the **'Databases'** folder). User must have name like your application pool in IIS Server. In `Default database` General tab set your using database. And then need to set for user next role: `sysadmin` in `Server Roles`

Comment: In the published website folder check logs file location in `web.config` and then check error in latest log file.

Comment: The Error message you're getting really tells you nothing. If you switch your production version over to 'development mode' you'll get a more helpful error message. If I were to make a wager, I'd say it was a Db connection. However, the possibilities you cite at the end of your post are all contenders as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: Open a command prompt to your site directory and run `dotnet MyApp.dll`, where `MyApp.dll` is your main application DLL. This will startup the site in the console, where you can see all the output, including exceptions being thrown. Make the same request that's giving you the error and look at the console out to see the exception. If you can't solve it on your own, post the full exception and stacktrace here.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I run my website like you written above: dotnet MSI.Site.dll
`C:\MSIEWebSite>dotnet MSIE.Site.dll
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\MSIEWebSite
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.`
In this case site work is normal

Comment: @ChrisPratt Also from Visual Studio 2017 (Debug /Release) site work is OK)
But if I start site from IIS Manager - "Manage Website" -> Browse then have a troubles. Main page of site showing is normal) When I try register or sign in - have error. Maybe I need change connection string in `appsettings.json` and `appsettings.production.json`?

Comment: And you *don't* get an error registering or signing in when you run the app from the console?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Exactly Chris. It surprises me

Comment: You're running from the same folder that's hosted in IIS?

Comment: @ChrisPratt Yes. It's folder where site located: `C:\MSIEWebSite`
And run site from command prompt: `C:\MSIEWebSite>dotnet MSIE.Site.dll`

Comment: @ChrisPratt Problem is solved. Thanks for your advice.
I have to add a new User which name the same with IIS Application Pools. And set role `sysadmin` in MSSMS -> Security -> Logins
Maybe exists other solution. It's will be cool know these.

Comment: Your connection string was trying to use integrated security. Don't use that in production. Create a new SQL user with limited read/write privileges, and then use that user and password in your connection string.

Comment: @ChrisPratt OK
Thank you very much
I'll keep it in mind

Comment: Your hint with the UseDeveloperExceptionPage has proven to be a salvation for me :-) Many thanks!